# NGINX | NextJS | Multiple Apps Dynamic _next/static files are not loading through alias

Tags: nginx, next.js, architecture, webserver, devops

I am facing issue while using "alias" property for NextJS Static files location block.
I was trying to make NextJS Static files location block as dynamic loading for multiple applications of NextJS using NGINX.

Facing weird issue as using static application path is working fine, but when I try to load it through dynamic mapping it is not working.

Here are below configuration:

**NGINX Server Configuration:**

```
worker_processes 1;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    log_format main '$http_x_forwarded_for - $remote_user [$time_local] "$host" "$request" '
            '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
            '"$http_user_agent" $request_time';

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;

    sendfile on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    client_max_body_size 200M;

    upstream wordpress {
        server wordpress:9000 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
    }

    upstream website {
        server website:3000 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
    }

    upstream discovery-app {
        server discovery-app:3001 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
    }

    upstream theme-food-2023 {
        server theme-food-2023:3002 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        access_log off;
        error_log off;
        server_name _;
        root /var/www/html;

        location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
            allow all;
            root /var/www/certbot;
        }

        location / {
            rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
        # server_name ^(www\.)?(?<domain>[^.]+)\.(?<tld>[^.]+)$;
        server_name ~^(www\.)?xyz.com;
        root /var/www/html;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/xyz.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/xyz.com/privkey.pem;
        ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/xyz.com/fullchain.pem;

        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" always;
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
        add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
        add_header Referrer-Policy "no-referrer-when-downgrade" always;
        add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src * data: 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'" always;



        location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
        }

        location = /favicon.ico {
            alias /var/www/next/static;
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
        }

        location = /robots.txt {
            alias /var/www/next/static;
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
            allow all;
        }

        location ~* \.(css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png)$ {
            expires max;
            log_not_found off;
        }

        location ^~ /_next {
            alias /var/www/next;
            try_files $uri =404;
            expires 365d;
            access_log off;
        }

        location ~ /(tools|know|themes)(.*)$ {
            proxy_pass http://website;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        }

        location ~ / {
            rewrite ^/(.*)$ /$1 break;
            proxy_pass http://website/?hostname=$host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            return 404;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;
        server_name ~^((?<subdomain>[^.]+)\.)?(?<domain>[^.]+\.[^.]+)$;

        root /var/www/html;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/xyz.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/xyz.com/privkey.pem;
        ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/xyz.com/fullchain.pem;

        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" always;
        add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
        add_header Referrer-Policy "no-referrer-when-downgrade" always;
        add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src * data: 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'" always;

        # Context of the configuration snippet 
        # ~ signifies a case-sensitive regular expression match.
        # ^~ ensures that this location block takes precedence over other location blocks with regular expression matches or prefix matches.
        # /(?<app_name>[^/]+)/_next is the regular expression pattern. It captures the part of the URL after the initial slash up to the next slash (/). The captured value is assigned to the variable app_name using the <app_name> named capturing group.
        

        # This gives me 404 error
        location ~ ^/(?<app_name>[^/]+)/_next {
            set $alias_path /var/www/apps/$app_name;
            alias $alias_path;
            # alias /var/www/apps/${app_name};
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            expires 365d;
            access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;
        }

        
        # This is giving 200 status code but still not working 
        # location ~ ^~/([^/]+)/_next {
        #   set $app_name $1;
        #   alias /var/www/apps/$app_name;
        #   try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        #   expires 365d;
        #   access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;
        # }

        #  Working perfectly
        # location /theme-food-2023/_next {
        #   alias /var/www/apps/theme-food-2023;
        #   try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        #   expires 365d;
        #   access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;
        # }

        location = /favicon.ico {
            alias /var/www/next/static;
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
        }

        location ~ ^/static {
            proxy_pass http://discovery-app;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        }

        location ~ ^/store/(?<theme>.+)/(?<store>.+)$ {
            proxy_pass http://${theme}/${store};
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        }

        location / {
            set $proxy_pass_address http://discovery-app/domain/$http_host;
           
            if ($http_host ~* "^([^.]+)\.xyz\.com$") {
                set $proxy_pass_address http://discovery-app/store/$subdomain;
            }

            proxy_pass $proxy_pass_address;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
            autoindex on;
            autoindex_exact_size on;
        }
    }
}
```

Facing Issues with below location blocks:

```
        # This gives me 404 error
        location ~ ^/(?<app_name>[^/]+)/_next {
            set $alias_path /var/www/apps/$app_name;
            alias $alias_path;
            # alias /var/www/apps/${app_name};
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            expires 365d;
            access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;
        }

        
        # This is giving 200 status code but still not working 
        # location ~ ^~/([^/]+)/_next {
        #   set $app_name $1;
        #   alias /var/www/apps/$app_name;
        #   try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        #   expires 365d;
        #   access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;
        # }

        #  Working perfectly
        # location /theme-food-2023/_next {
        #   alias /var/www/apps/theme-food-2023;
        #   try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        #   expires 365d;
        #   access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;
        # }
```

Last location blocks works properly. Added comment on working location block as "Working perfectly".
But when I am trying to make it dynamically load the alias where my multiple NextJS apps are running it is not working, But it perfectly works on static configuration.

Tried multiple approaches. Here are examples:

```
        # This gives me 404 error
        location ~ ^/(?<app_name>[^/]+)/_next {
            set $alias_path /var/www/apps/$app_name;
            alias $alias_path;
            # alias /var/www/apps/${app_name};
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            expires 365d;
            access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;
        }

        
        # This is giving 200 status code but still not working 
        # location ~ ^~/([^/]+)/_next {
        #   set $app_name $1;
        #   alias /var/www/apps/$app_name;
        #   try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        #   expires 365d;
        #   access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;
        # }

        #  Working perfectly
        # location /theme-food-2023/_next {
        #   alias /var/www/apps/theme-food-2023;
        #   try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        #   expires 365d;
        #   access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;
        # }
```

Expecting to load NextJS statics files to load dynamically from the specific NEXTJS application from the multiple apps.